# tweepy how to get a username from id

Tags: python, tweepy

how do I derrive a plaintext username from a user Id number with tweepy?

Here is the CORRECTED code that I am using:

```
ids = []
userid = "someOne"
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=userid).pages():
     ids.extend(page)
     time.sleep(60)

print len(ids), "following have been gathered from", userid  

users = api.lookup_users(user_ids=ids)#ieterates through the list of users and prints them
for u in users:
    print u.screen_name
```

The last line I have commented is the one giving me an issue. Please advise. Thank you all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are iterating `ids` and `i` already contains element of `ids`. Try to pass `i` to `lookup_users`:

```
for i in ids:
    print screen_name(api.lookup_users(i))
    # print screen_name(api.lookup_users(ids[i]))
```

**update**, try this way:

```
users = api.lookup_users(user_ids=ids)
for u in users:
    print u.screen_name
```