# Tweepy lookup_user missing argument

Tags: python, tweepy

I have the following script:

```
import sys, json, os, io, re, time
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import TweepError
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
ACCSS_SECRET = ''
user_ids = ['1123728482', '5539932']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
    API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

    try:
        test = API.lookup_users(user_ids=user_ids)
        print(test)
    except TweepError as e:
        print('Something went wrong, quitting...', e)
        time.sleep(15 * 60)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
test = API.lookup_users(user_ids=user_ids)
TypeError: lookup_users() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I checked the [official documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup), the [source code](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/80015db395bdd19700390ed5d0742c7b6d5996d2/tweepy/api.py#L311) and this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233905/python-tweepy-twitter-api-saying-that-users-lookup-does-not-exist) but I still not sure what I am doing wrong..

Thak you

Answer (score 0):

I needed to initialize the class..

```
 API = API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```